# How to remove the title from a data table in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

Is there a way to keep the data table but remove the values' title (highlighted in red)?

I would like to keep the legend however..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done. You could change the series name to a blank, but then there'd be an empty box where you circled, and the legend would be useless.

An alternative is to build a data table manually using normal cells just below the chart. With some clever formatting like using borders and disabling the chart's background fill color, you can make it look like it is attached to the bottom chart.